# Decreasing the directed chromatic number of a digraph by adding an edge

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, directed-graphs

The chromatic number of an undirected graph can never be decreased by adding an edge. However, things are not that clear when we deal with coloring directed graphs - but first, the definition of this concept in the context of directed graphs.

If $X$ is a non-empty set, we say that $M\subseteq X$ is a *majority* if $|M| > |X\setminus M|$.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite directed graph. For $v\in V$ we set $\text{In}(v)=\{x \in V: (x,v) \in E\}$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. We say that a map $c:V(G) \to \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a *majority coloring* if the following condition is satisfied:

> For every $v\in V(G)$ with $\text{In}(v) \neq \emptyset$, if for some $k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ we have that $c^{-1}(\{k\}) \cap \text{In}(v)$ is a majority of $\text{In}(v)$, then $c(v) \neq k$.

We set the *(directed) chromatic number* $\chi_d(G)$ to be the least positive integer $j$ such that there is a majority coloring $c:V(G) \to \{1,\ldots,j\}$.

Is there a directed graph $G$ such that adding an edge decreases the directed chromatic number?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood correctly. If I consider an undirected graph as a directed graph with arrows going both ways, then the directed chromatic number and the chromatic number are not necessarily equal?

Comment: That's correct, there is even [a conjecture](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v24i2p25/pdf) saying that the directed chromatic number is at most $3$ for every finite graph (every finite digraph can be colored with $4$ colors, see Theorem 1 of [this paper](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v24i2p25/pdf).)

Comment: In that paper, there is an example of a digraph on 4 vertices which shows that being majority $c$-colourable is not closed under taking induced subgraphs. The same example shows that the removal of one edge can increase the "majority chromatic number".

Comment: Thanks @DavidHackenger - I missed this! Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it, and close this thread? Many thanks!